# im traying to make a button to shared a info with the windows modal

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

im traying to make a button to shared a info with the windows modal but i dont know how to make in angular

[windowsModal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u97pv.png)

[options iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvgrD.png)
maybe someone know how to make this.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by that? There can be to ways to do this. The first is this:

if your using jquery i suggest doing thing

```
$("#modalActivator").click(function(){ //modal activator is the id of the button your using to show the modal
$("#modalDiv").show(1000); //modal div is the id of your modal. doesn't have to be modal div.
}
$("#modalDeactivator).click(function(){ //modal deactivator is the close button of your modal.
 $("#modalDiv").hide(1000);
}
```

You didn't have much context to your request so this is the best i can do with the information.

Comment: i'm trying to make a button to share, but i need the button to display the windows or iphone or android modal, could you see this page https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.co/MCO-606065381-crocs-literide-chispas-hombre-y-mujer-_JM#reco_item_pos=2&reco_backend=machinalis-homes&reco_backend_type=function&reco_client=home_navigation-recommendations&reco_id=79d7c447-40ef-442b-a849-027487990c2c&c_id=/home/navigation-recommendations/element&c_element_order=3&c_uid=d0628e2f-87f9-4f80-8c98-422962ca704a  --  and clic in the share button i need something like that modal.